# PHP Composer failed to open stream - Permission Denied

Tags: php, composer-php, permission-denied

I've come across a strange issue with regards to the use of composer in my current PHP project.

Some of the answers on S.O that relate to this issue have been helpful, in the sense that changing folder permissions to `0755` on the root composer folder as well as subsequent sub folders and files, resolves the issue; however this seems to be temporary.

My PHP script breaks at the line where I `require("vendor/autoload.php")`. It then only resolves when I change the folder and file permissions to `0755`; but every new day I find that the issue persists, then I have to set the permissions again. It's as if the permissions on the folders and files reset at irregular intervals.

Intitially I thought this could be an auto-update issue, however from what I've researched, composer does not auto-update itself by default unless manually doing so.

Your assistance will be greatly appreciated. I'm dumbfounded as to why this happens.

Comment: could you tell me which OS you are using and where you placed the composer.phar file ?

Comment: Certainly. I'm running on a 64 bit platform with Linux OS and Centos 6.7. My current composer.phar file is located in a sub directory on one of my sub domains. For example: subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory/vendor/composer.phar. I used composer's auto-installer via SSH when having installed composer.

Comment: could you give `chmod -R 777` and check again ! If you are using any framework like laravel / symfony clear cache then test again !

Comment: Are you using a VM ?